# why shows expected identifier when using diesel ext command to generate the rust diesel 2.x model

Tags: rust

I using rust diesel cli to generate the diesel 2.x(`diesel = { version = "2.0.4", features = ["postgres","64-column-tables","chrono","serde_json"] }`) model using this shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -u
set -e
set -x

PROJECT_DIR="$(dirname "$(cargo locate-project|jq -r .root)")"

diesel_ext --derive Insertable,Queryable,QueryableByName,Debug,Serialize,Deserialize,Default,Clone \
--map "Jsonb serde_json::Value" \
--add-table-name \
--import-types "serde::Serialize" \
--import-types "serde::Deserialize" \
--import-types "crate::model::diesel::tex::tex_schema::*" \
--schema-file "${PROJECT_DIR}"/src/model/diesel/tex/tex_schema.rs --model > "${PROJECT_DIR}"/src/model/diesel/tex/tex_models.rs
```

the generate model file look like this:

```
// Generated by diesel_ext

#![allow(unused)]
#![allow(clippy::all)]

use serde::Serialize;
use serde::Deserialize;
use crate::model::diesel::tex::tex_schema::*;

#[derive(Insertable,Queryable,QueryableByName,Debug,Serialize,Deserialize,Default,Clone)]
#[diesel(table_name = "tex_doc")]
pub struct TexDoc {
    pub id: i64,
    pub doc_name: String,
    pub created_time: i64,
    pub updated_time: i64,
    pub user_id: i64,
    pub doc_status: i32,
    pub template_id: i64,
}
```

but the compiler shows error like this:

```
   Compiling texhub-server v0.1.0 (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/texhub-server)
error: expected identifier
  --> src/model/diesel/tex/custom_tex_models.rs:11:23
   |
11 | #[diesel(table_name = "tex_doc")]
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^
```

why did this happen? what should I do to fixed this error?

Comment: Without knowing Diesel at all, you probably need `table_name = tex_doc`.